# Wordpress: Blog in Blog Plugin adding pre/code

Tags: wordpress, plugins

So I have been using blog in blog on my localhost before making it ready for online use.
once online i upload everything and notice that my css is different, and i can't solve it.

Could anyone explain why a pre and code tag have been added?
(see images below for more details)

[Localhost - Developer Tools](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/7/lohost.jpg/)

[Web - Developer Tools](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/89/webaz.jpg/)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blog-in-blog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, it was caused by copying and pasting.
*should have read that it said not to copy and past :|*